# Post not saved in first click, but saved in second click "Save" Yii

Tags: php, yii

When i am create new post in Yii on scenario 'create', i have two fields 'short description' and 'long description', so when i am click first Save i have a message error 'Short Description cannot be blank.' and post not save, if i am click second then post is save.
How i can fix it?

P.S. When i am delete this fields from rules post save in first click.

```
array('title, price, short_description, long_description, store, in_stock', 'required', 'on'=>'general, create'),
```

Thanks!

This is happened coz i use some extension for textarea

```
'short_description'=>array(
            'type'=>'textarea',
            'cols'=>50,
            'rows'=>10,
        ),
        'long_description'=>array(
            'type'=>'textarea',
            'cols'=>50,
            'rows'=>14,
        ),
```

When i am replace textarea to text field all work good.

But i am need fix it, have any one think?

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('title, price, short_description, long_description, store, in_stock', 'required', 'on'=>'general, create'),
        array('short_description', 'length', 'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'max'=>256),
        array('product_number, weight', 'safe', 'on'=>'general, create'),
        array('price, in_stock', 'numerical', 'on'=>'general, create'),
        array('price', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => FALSE, 'min' => '0', 'on'=>'general, create'),
        array('in_stock', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => FALSE, 'min' => '0', 'on'=>'general, create'),
        array('store','trialCreate','on'=>'create'),
        array('status', 'safe', 'on'=>'create'),
        array('meta_description, meta_keywords', 'safe', 'on'=>'meta'),
        array('currentImage', 'safe', 'on'=>'image'),
        array('newImage', 'file', 'allowEmpty'=>false, 'safe'=>true, 'types'=>'png, jpg, jpeg, gif', 'on'=>'image'),
        array('categoryIDs', 'validateCategories', 'on'=>'categories'),
        array('status', 'required', 'on'=>'status'),
        array('store', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Put controller not easy, coz i am use a crud

So, i am use this way for me. I am remove fields from rules required and created own rules.

```
array('short_description, long_description', 'validateDescription', 'on'=>'general, create'),

/**
 *
*/
public function validateDescription()
{
    if($this->long_description=="")
    {
        $this->addError('long_description', 'Long Description cannot be blank.');
    }
    if($this->short_description=="")
    {
        $this->addError('short_description', 'Short Description cannot be blank.');
    }
}
```

And now i need create validation on client side.
Thanks all for attention!

Comment: What extension are you using for the textArea?

Comment: thanks. And the '$model->save()' or '$model->create()' call? only is for show how are you putting the '$model->attributes'

Comment: I am use crud for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, if you use this restriction allways? (In all scenarios)

```
array('title, price, short_description, long_description, store, in_stock', 'required'),
```

**Edited:**

Can you put your model/controller code, please?

**Edited:**

Try with **CActiveForm** widget:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                  'id'=>'myModel-form',
                  'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'short_description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'short_description',array('maxlength'=>255, 'cols'=>50, 'rows'=>10)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'short_description'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'long_description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'long_description',array('maxlength'=>255, 'cols'=>50, 'rows'=>14)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'long_description'); ?>
</div>


<div>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save', array('class'=>'btn')); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not help.

Comment: "When i am replace textarea to text field all work good." you have not written before, and it's a important point..

Comment: I am understand, before i don't know it, now i think i am need find why editor conflict with Yii client validator js or remove required field in rules and create own.